# Count New Response and Cumulative Percent Per Month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I have several customers responding month after month, I want to count them only in the first month they responded. I can achieve this by creating temp tables for each month and comparing month over month, but it looks ugly with several temp tables. I'm pretty sure that there's a better way to do this (I don't know if Rank() will work). Can someone show me code please?

```
    declare @Something table
(
    CustID Char(10),
    MthId char(2),
    ResponseDate datetime
)
```

insert @Something
select 'Cust1', '1', '5/6/13' union all
select 'Cust1', '2', '6/13/13' union all
select 'Cust1', '3', '7/13/13' union all
select 'Cust2', '1', '5/20/13' union all
select 'Cust2', '2', '6/22/13' union all
select 'Cust3', '2', '6/20/13' union all
select 'Cust4', '2', '6/24/13' union all
select 'Cust4', '3', '7/24/13' union all
select 'Cust5', '4', '8/28/13' union all
select 'Cust6', '3', '7/24/13'

This is the output I'm expecting in 3 columns (I don't really need the 2nd col - it's there to explain further)

Month, How many "cumulative" new customers responded that month, What's the cumulative percent of total customers contacted new every month.

```
MthId   NewCustomerResponse CumulativeNewCustomerResponse Cumulative%Responded    
1       2                     2                            33.3     
2       2                     4                            66.7     
3       1                     5                            83.3 
4       1                     6                            100.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including your new column:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26889) to the solution

```
;with cte as(
select 
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CustID order by responseDate) as seq
,* from @Something
)
,cte2 as( 
select 
 MthId
,(select Count(*) from cte t2 where t1.MthId=t2.MthId and t2.seq=1) NewCustomerResponse
,(select COUNT(*) from cte t2 where t1.MthId>=t2.MthId and t2.seq=1)     CumulativeNewCustomerResponse
,(select COUNT(CustID) from cte where seq=1) total
from cte t1
group by MthId
)

select 
MthID
,NewCustomerResponse
,CumulativeNewCustomerResponse
,(cast(CumulativeNewCustomerResponse as decimal(3,1))/CAST(total as decimal(3,1)))*100
from cte2 t1
```

Answer (score 1):

check this,

```
 declare @Something table
    (
        CustID Char(10),
        MthId char(2),
        ResponseDate datetime
    )
    insert into @Something
     select 'Cust1', '1', '5/6/13' 
     union all 
     select 'Cust1', '2', '6/13/13' 
     union all 
     select 'Cust1', '3', '7/13/13' 
     union all 
     select 'Cust2', '1', '5/20/13' 
     union all 
     select 'Cust2', '2', '6/22/13' 
     union all
     select 'Cust3', '2', '6/20/13' union all
    select 'Cust4', '2', '6/24/13' union all
    select 'Cust4', '3', '7/24/13' union all
    select 'Cust5', '4', '8/28/13' union all
    select 'Cust6', '3', '7/24/13'

    ;with CTE as
    (select *,dense_rank()over(partition by custid order by mthid)rn from @Something)
    ,CTE1 as
    (select a.MthId,count(*) NewCustomerResponse  from cte a where rn=1 group by a.MthId )
    ,cte2 as
    (select sum(NewCustomerResponse) totalresponse from cte1)
,cte4 as
(
select  a.MthId
,(Select sum(NewCustomerResponse)  from CTE1 c where c.mthid<=a.mthid) CumulativeNewCustomerResponse

from cte1 a cross apply cte2 b
)





   select  a.MthId,a.NewCustomerResponse
,(Select sum(NewCustomerResponse)from CTE1 c where c.mthid<=a.mthid)CumulativeNewCustomerResponse 
,case when b.totalresponse>0 then cast((d.CumulativeNewCustomerResponse /cast(b.totalresponse as float))*100 as decimal(10,2)) else 0 end [Cumulative%Responded] 
from cte1 a 
inner join cte4 d on a.MthId=d.MthId
cross apply cte2 b
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I realized that I actually needed the NewCustomerResponse to be cumulative as well. I've edited my post. Could you please show how to get that column (3rd col) as well?

Comment: For that matter you can simply add a subquery in your final select: `,(select COUNT(*) from cte t2 where t1.MthId>=t2.MthId and t2.seq=1) CumulativeNewCustomerResponse from cte`

Comment: The subquery is not working, Kiril.
KumarHarsh or anyone, could you edit the original answer to include the column I'm asking, please..

Comment: check the latest query

Comment: KumarHarsh, thanks. But the Cumulative%Responded col value is not cumulative after your edit.